# dynamic textboxes inside updatepnael

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am creating an asp.net page which has a dropdownlist with values 0,1,2,3,4 inside updatepanel

When user will click 0 element, I want to create one textbox and a button. when user will click the button, value of textbox should be shown in label without postback

When user clicks element 1, then two textboxes should be shown, 3 for element 2 and so on.

Please suggest solution.

[Edited]

private int tblRows = 5;
        private int tblCols = 1;

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateDynamicTable();
    }

    private void CreateDynamicTable()
    {

        if( ViewState["tbl"] != null && ViewState["tbl"].ToString() == "true"){
        // Fetch the number of Rows and Columns for the table
        // using the properties

        // Now iterate through the table and add your controls
            for (int i = 0; i < tblRows; i++)
            {
                TableRow tr = new TableRow();
                for (int j = 0; j < tblCols; j++)
                {
                    TableCell tc = new TableCell();
                    TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
                    txtBox.ID = "txt-" + i.ToString() + "-" + j.ToString();
                    txtBox.Text = "RowNo:" + i + " " + "ColumnNo:" + " " + j;
                    // Add the control to the TableCell
                    tc.Controls.Add(txtBox);
                    // Add the TableCell to the TableRow
                    tr.Cells.Add(tc);

                }
                // Add the TableRow to the Table
                tbl.Rows.Add(tr);
                tbl.EnableViewState = true;
                ViewState["tbl"] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void btnSet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (TableRow tr in tbl.Controls)
        {
            foreach (TableCell tc in tr.Controls)
            {

                if (tc.Controls[0] is TextBox)
                {
                    Response.Write(((TextBox)tc.Controls[0]).Text);
                }
            }
            Response.Write("<br/>");
        }

    }

    protected override object SaveViewState()
    {
        object[] newViewState = new object[2];

        List<string> txtValues = new List<string>();

        foreach (TableRow row in tbl.Controls)
        {
            foreach (TableCell cell in row.Controls)
            {
                if (cell.Controls[0] is TextBox)
                {
                    txtValues.Add(((TextBox)cell.Controls[0]).Text);
                }
            }
        }

        newViewState[0] = txtValues.ToArray();
        newViewState[1] = base.SaveViewState();
        return newViewState;
    }
    protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
    {
        //if we can identify the custom view state as defined in the override for SaveViewState
        if (savedState is object[] && ((object[])savedState).Length == 2 && ((object[])savedState)[0] is string[])
        {
            object[] newViewState = (object[])savedState;
            string[] txtValues = (string[])(newViewState[0]);
            if (txtValues.Length > 0)
            {
                //re-load tables
                CreateDynamicTable();
                int i = 0;
                foreach (TableRow row in tbl.Controls)
                {
                    foreach (TableCell cell in row.Controls)
                    {
                        if (cell.Controls[0] is TextBox && i < txtValues.Length)
                        {
                            ((TextBox)cell.Controls[0]).Text = txtValues[i++].ToString();

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //load the ViewState normally
            base.LoadViewState(newViewState[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            base.LoadViewState(savedState);
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateDynamicTable();
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: I am able to create the dynamic textboxes with postback ( without updatepanel) but when I use updatepanel, It is not working. textboxes need to be created on dropdown selected index change only

Comment: Can you show the relevant code ?

Comment: @Coder Please see code... I want to do it using  updatepanel and dropdownlist

Comment: I meant to show your relevant markup code for updatepanel and dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two dificulties in this.
   **First:** Create two or more controls without postback.
   **Second:** Call a method to get the data from a textbox and place in a label, also without postback.

I think i can help only with the **Second** part of the solution, i think. 
To interact with controls without postback (whitch means, to work only on the client side) i can only suggest to add a function in javascript in the web form's header. Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function DysplayTextInLabel (){
         // This function get the text from TextBoxID and place in the LabelID
         var TxtData document.getElementbyId("<%=TextBoxID.ClientID%>").value;
         document.getElementbyId("<%=LabelID.ClientID%>").innerHTML = TxtData;
    }
</script>
```

Then you have to use a Client-Side Event caller to call the *DysplayTextInLabel* function. Since all buttons have auto-postback and even if you set *autopostback = false* in the aspx code, it will still refresh the page you have to to this in you code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateDynamicTable();
    // The (!isPostBack) will verify if is the first time run of the code 
    if(!isPostBack){
        // This will remove the postback from button2
        Button2.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "return false;");
        // This will execute the DysplayTextInLabel without postback 
        Button2.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "return DysplayTextInLabel();");
    }
}
```

This code will work for an already created Button (Button2) because we are interacting with it in the Page_Load. For a button created dynamicaly in the client side i cant help you, but i can only point to research javascript functions for the **First** part of the problem.
I hope this can help you. Good Luck.